# Apache Maven Data And Config Files Output Directory

Tags: java, maven, directory

I'm new and have question. I couldn't find answer for my question on internet (or I missed it). So here is my question, I have some plugins on my POM. (`JavaDoc`, `Surefire`, `JXR`, `Cobertura` and `Checkstyle`). What I want is change their directory of all datas, configurations and other similar files to `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources`

I tried `<reportsDirectory>` and `<outputDirectory>` but nothing happened. I think I'm doing something wrong.

```
    <reporting>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                <reportsDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/resources</reportsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            .
            .
            .
   </reporting>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: outputDirectory parameter is only relevant if the report plugin is run standalone, i.e. by invocation directly from the command line. In contrast, when reports are generated as part of the site, the configuration of the Maven Site Plugin will determine the effective output directory to ensure that all reports end up in a common location. -- Courtesy https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/configuring-reports.html

Comment: Don't change the default folder layout and *never change it to a location which is under version control like `src/...`* ...All generated parts etc. also reporting is generated into `target/...` ...The question is why are you trying to change that? What kind of issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: Hello thanks for reply. I'm doing project for my school. So teacher wants it :)